# create ruby definition on irb load

Tags: ruby

I would like to have a clear function in my irb console, but there isn't one.  Here's what I type in every time I load irb from the terminal:

```
def cls
  system 'clear'
end
```

It's not real hard to type this each time a load irb, but it would certainly be nice to have this function load automatically when irb starts.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Use an .irbrc file? E.g., http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/using-irbrc-file-to-configure-your-irb/

Comment: Also, `readline` applications (such as `irb`) support clearing the screen by pressing Ctrl-L.

Comment: Dave - that's exactly correct, I didn't realize I could do this.  Since you didn't add your comment as an answer, I can't select it as the solution!

Answer (score 1):

When *irb* is starting up, it looks for the file `.irbrc` in your home directory. If the file exists, it evaluates it. So this file is the perfect place to add some generic stuff to irb...

For inspiration, mine looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pp'
require 'irb/ext/save-history'

# add $HOME/lib to the load path
$: << '~/lib'

IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 1000
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"


def real_instance_methods_of(klass)
  klass.instance_methods - ((klass.ancestors - [klass]).map(&:instance_methods).flatten)
end

class Class
  def instance_methods_defined_here
    real_instance_methods_of self
  end
end

# more stuff...
# ...
```

*EDIT: I just noticed the comment by Dave Newton now; he already pointed out the .irbrc solution...*

Answer (score -2):

on a mac just hit CMD + K to clear the screen

Comment: This is a very narrow answer. Where does he mention anything about Mac?

Comment: ...except for all those Ruby users on Linux or Windows.

Comment: it's a joke, have a little fun. and a downvote? if he's on a mac it's a valid solution.

Comment: How does Ruby imply a Mac? Meh; of course it's a valid solution if you're in a Mac. Of course, if you're on a Mac, ctrl-l would work just as well, without deleting your scroll buffer. In general we prefer asking a question if you have one instead of guessing, though.

Comment: @StuartNelson: Acceptance of humor on SO is whimsical :), but not absent, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348).